# How to replace "v-bind:class" Template Feature with Plain JavaScript in Render function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Or may be there is other more easy way to do that without Plain JavaScript??? So, I don't understand how to bind my object with CSS classes to my template that I want to create with render function. I have only one way and I have to use plain javascipt? Or may I didn't understand something in documentation and there are some Ready solutions given by Vue?

I need to get the same affect with render function as this:

```
<template>
    <h1 v-bind:class="myClass"></h1>
</template>
<script>
    export default { 
      data(){
          return:{
              myClass: true,
          };
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @yev Thanks. I corrected that mistake. But was it the main problem of your misunderstanding  of my question?  Explanation of my question:  I know hove to bind it in usual way using "v-bind", as I showed. In my case, I wont make the same affect with using Render Function to create an element. How/where to bind my object with CSS class inside Render function? Is there some ways to do that? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so.

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      myClass: true,
    }
  },
  render(h){
    const data = {
      'class': {
        myClass: this.myClass
      }
    }
    return h("h1", data, "Hello World")
  }
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/KmpLbV).

See [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth) here.

You can see that this is reactive.

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      myClass: true,
    }
  },
  methods:{
    clickHandler(){
      this.myClass = !this.myClass
    }
  },
  render(h){
    const data = {
      'class': {
        myClass: this.myClass
      }
    }
    return h("h1", data, [
      "Hello World",
      h("button", {on: {click: this.clickHandler}}, "Toggle")
    ])
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that. It gives opportunity to put object with class inside element. But its not reactive as usual "v-bind". I'm trying to say, that if you will change the value of your 'class' property, changes wouldn't be automatically done in your HTML element.

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko If you want it to be reactive, then you likely want to pass whether to set it or not through a property.

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko I modified the example and it's definitely reactive. Click the button, changes myClass, re-renders.

Comment: @BeartEvans  In my situation I want to be reactive working with data() properties. Because, state/value of objects with classes depends from computing inside component

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko I updated the example such that it completely changes the class depending on the data. In any case you can see it still works. I'm not sure what your issue is. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/KmpLbV

Comment: Yes. I see that it works nice. Thank you vary mach fore your time and examples! I'v get to the next stage that calls by me: "Now I now it works, but I don't understand why it doesn't work in my code. I'm not talking about examples in this topic. Just abut my code on my machine. Ohhhh

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko Possibly you might want to update your question, or ask another question with your specific code. Good luck :)

Comment: I found the problem. The problem was strange as for me. So. I decided to ask one more question. May be you will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459106/name-the-rules-and-demands-that-define-when-render-function-must-run

Answer (score 0):

If you want apply class "myClass" you should do so:

```
<template>
  <h1 :class="{myClass: isActive}"></h1>
</template>
<script>
    export default { 
      data(){
          return:{
              isActive: true
          };
      }
    }
</script>
```

See vue doc: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: You didn't understand the question. I know hove to bind it in usual way, as you just showed. In my case, I wont make the same affect with using Render Function to create an element.