# Name the Rules and Demands that define When Render function must Run?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When and why [Render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) will re-render vue component. May be some one know some Rules and Demands to data?

Comment: The render function isn't the key, but rather the reactivity that invokes the render function.  See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: Reactivity in Depth - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

If you are more of a visual person... then the lifecycle diagram might be easier to understand - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Basically any time a reactive data property changes... Vue will re-render the component.